# Formatting a string value within a JOptionPane

Tags: java, text, string-formatting, joptionpane

I want to format a string, so instead of the value reading: 1.599999, it reads 1.59. For the rest of my program, I've been using: %.2f to format the JLabels, but when I try do that in a JOptionPane, it doesn't recognize it as format code, but as text.

EDIT:

```
  amountEntered = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(finishPayInput, "Please enter the full total of: £%.2f" + convPrice);
```

Comment: share some code with us to get better and faster help ;)

Comment: @Zorian code added! :)

Comment: look, you added code and get a direct answer ;) Remind it next time

Answer (score 1):

```
amountEntered = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(finishPayInput,
    String.format("Please enter the full total of: £%.2f", convPrice))
```

Answer (score 1):

Split it out into a String variable and put it inline (I avoid putting it directly inline for smaller lines of code and easier debugging, personal preference though):

```
String fullTotal = String.format("Please enter the full total of: £%.2f", convPrice);
amountEntered = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(finishPayInput, fullTotal);
```

Comment: Oops, @JoopEggen that my comment was not directed at you. Your answer was put up while I worked on mine